# Run multiple Android Emulators in Ubuntu.

Tags: android

How can I run multiple Android instances in Ubuntu and have a single point of control for all of the instances?I want to install clash of clans on 50 android devices running on my pc and then send a click command to all 50 through the terminal.

Comment: This is offtopic, but I can help you get started, maybe... First, download "Android AVD", second, configure as many Androids as you want, third, write a python script (or something else) that does `adb shell input tap x y` with all devices (for loop) when it receives something. Done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was able to run just 2 android devices. Can you tell me how to maximize no. of emulators with limited RAM of 4GB?

Comment: In the AVD config of each device you can limit the RAM individually. So theoretically if you give 200MB each, you should be abre to run 5 with 1GB, 10 with 2GB and so on. You must take into consideration that you must reserve ~1GB for Linux itself. And 200MB RAM is maybe too little for a game. If it shouldn't work, try getting an RAM upgrade to 6 or 8GB...

Answer (score 0):

in windows this is ez with noxplayer, unfortunately i cannot get nox to run in ubuntu

nox lets to toggle all instances to mirror one, it can key bind swipes and moves to the keyboard, it can make/run it's own macros so if you want to have all 50 windows collect all resources every hour just run the macro on an hour cd

if i could get something that did all that in linux i'd use linux, untill then windows is the only option :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35071546)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).